# Error with parser recognising regex

Tags: c#, javascript, regex, validation, email-validation

I am trying to add a bit of JavaScript validation to my application to check that an email address is formatted correctly.

This is the code that I am using to perform the validation checks:

```
var bValid = true;
allFields.removeClass( "ui-state-error" );
bValid = bValid && checkLength( email, "email", 6, 80 );
bValid = bValid && checkLength( password, "password", 5, 16 );
bValid = bValid && checkRegexp( name, /^[a-z]([0-9a-z_])+$/i, "Username may consist of a-z, 0-9, underscores, begin with a letter." );
// From jquery.validate.js (by joern), contributed by Scott Gonzalez: http://projects.scottsplayground.com/email_address_validation/
var reg = /^(([^<>()[]\.,;:s@"]+(.[^<>()[]\.,;:s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@(([[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z-0-9]+.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
bValid = bValid && checkRegexp(email, reg, "eg. smith@hotmail.com");
bValid = bValid && checkRegexp( password, /^([0-9a-zA-Z])+$/, "Password field only allow : a-z 0-9" );
if ( bValid ) {
    //DO ajax call
    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
}
```

And I am getting this error:

[image]

I have tried numerous examples of regex expressions but all get caught by the parser.

Comment: you are missing quotes var reg = @"YOUR REGEX HERE";

Comment: @isi, its JavaScript, not C#. So the `/.../` literals are fine (placing an `@` in front of it will result in more errors): the problem is most probably as M42 indicated.

Comment: ok :) then sry about that

Comment: What I don't understand is why is the server giving an error for your JavaScript code? Isn't JavaScript supposed to run on the client browser?

Answer (score 2):

Escape the `]` inside character class:

```
var reg = /^(([^<>()[\]\.,;:s@"]+(.[^<>()[\]\.,;:s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@(([[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z-0-9]+.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
//            here __^             here __^
```

Not sure but javascript may want to escape also `[` :

```
var reg = /^(([^<>()\[\]\.,;:s@"]+(.[^<>()\[\]\.,;:s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@(([[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z-0-9]+.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
//           here __^              here __^
```

Comment: i think escaping is just another issue, but the first issue is according missing quotes for the regex string, or is the "/" a syntactical shorthand in C# to indicate a regex?

Comment: @isi: Not for javascript.

Comment: tried to add escapes where you mentioned but got the same error?

Comment: @M42 any other ideas?

Comment: Thanks, Though I am getting a bit confused with what needs escaping, could you add the escape characters in your example?

Comment: @BrianPeach: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/399078/what-special-characters-must-be-escaped-in-regular-expressions

Answer (score 0):

Based on what [Chirag64](https://stackoverflow.com/users/976897/chirag64) wrote, it looks like the server might be mistakenly running your JavaScript code? Line 104 is perhaps just the first line where the compiler/interpreter has an error due to it being the wrong language? What programming language is your server expecting?

You should try copying and pasting the problem code into a separate HTML file and see if it will run there when you load it directly into a browser (no server). I suspect that it will.